# Polars explode columns, ComputeError columns mismatch

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a list column and two different columns, I would like to explode the list column while keeping the two other columns  e.g.

| a | b | list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "q" | "p" | ["hello","bye"] |

to

| a | b | list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "q" | "p" | "hello" |
| "q" | "p" | "bye" |

but with

```
pl.select(
    pl.exclude("list"),
    pl.col("list").explode())
```

I get a length mismatch

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for the dataframe method: `df.explode("list")`

Comment: Yes, just found it thanks :)